# How can I display Simplified Chinse in RDLC

Tags: .net, chinese-locale

I am building report using RDLC of asp.net. But I want to type in some simplified chinese text in the report. But I cannot find a simplified Chinese font or unicode font. How can I input Simplified Chinese font/

Thanks

Comment: You want to set chinese text in the RDLC Text Box or something else right?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing the textbox font property?
[image: font property]